# Composite primary key for 1-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Well, I was always doing it like this:

```
create table language (
  id bigserial primary key,
  code varchar(10) not null
);

create table entity (
  id bigserial primary key
);

create table entity_description (

  id bigserial primary key,

  language_id bigint not null,

  constraint fk__entity_description__language
    foreign key language_id
    references language(id),

  entity_id bigint not null,

  constraint fk__entity_description__entity
    foreign key entity_id
    references entity(id),

  name varchar(20) not null
);
```

but I wonder.. *why* wouldn't I do it like this:

```
create table language (
  id bigserial primary key,
  code varchar(10) not null
);

create table entity (
  id bigserial primary key
);

create table entity_description (

  language_id bigint not null,

  constraint fk__entity_description__language
    foreign key language_id
    references language(id),

  entity_id bigint not null,

  constraint fk__entity_description__entity
    foreign key entity_id
    references entity(id),

  primary key (language_id, entity_id),

  name varchar(20) not null
);
```

My questions are

- Is there anything that speaks against the composite primary key in the second example?
- Are there any benefits?
- Are, in the second example, `(language_id, entity_id)`, `language_id` and `entity_id` indexed separately for table `entity_description`? If I fetch for 
  `.. WHERE entity_description.id = x`
   is this slower than fetching for 
   `.. WHERE (entity_description.language_id, entity_description.entity_id) = (x,y)`?

Comment: My question is, "Why do you need two tables?"

Comment: I don't see any **benefit** in having a PK made up from two columns, if one of them alone is already a candidate key, e.g. uniquely and reliably identifies each row. What benefit do you see in adding a second column to that index? It just makes referencing that table from other tables harder (you **must have** both columns in the composite PK in those tables, and you must always specify both columns in any `JOIN` that you have), and it really doesn't offer any positive benefit of any kind....

Comment: @DanBracuk I am sorry, it was late. I edited my example so it makes more sense. `entity_details` is now a translational table.

Comment: 0) It is quite normal for NxM *junction tables* like this to have composite keys (think of the key elements as strong domains). 1) The PRIMARY KEY constraint automagically creates a unique index in postgres. An index will also be used if only the first key element(s) is specified. In most cases you'll also want a composite index with the key elements in reversed order.

Comment: @joop The downside is of course if `entity_description` has another m:n relation with another table, that junction table has a primary key of at least 2 + (size of other table pk) columns: language_id, entity_id, <other-table-pk>. You are mentioning the ordering of the pk: until now I didn't even know that this makes a difference but this makes kind of sense. So what I want is actually a lexicographical ordering of the pk e.g. singe language_id is very often the same, it's maybe better to have (entity_id, language_id) instead of the other way around. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Don't complicate things before you understand the basics. If you want a ternary junction table: do go ahead, but please put that in another question.